# How to get value in edittext from a Radio Groups in Popup Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-radiobutton

I am designing a registration form where I have one EditText field for Categories.  This list of categories is opened as a radio group in separate Popup activity when we click in EditText field.  It is working fine till popup.  However, I am not able to get the value back in the EditText field after selecting the RadioButton in the Popup activity.

Activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.security.PublicKey;

public class Industry extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_industry );

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics ();
        getWindowManager ().getDefaultDisplay ().getMetrics ( dm );

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow ().setLayout ( (int)(width*.9),(int)(height*.85) );

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow ().getAttributes ();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = -20;

        getWindow ().setAttributes ( params );



    }

}
```

.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Industry">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rbtnGroupIndus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Agriculture And Allied Industries"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Automobiles"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Auto Components"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aviation"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Banking"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cement"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Consumer Durables"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ecommerce"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Education And Training"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Engineering And Capital Goods"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Financial Services"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fmcg"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gems And Jewellery"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Healthcare"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Infrastructure"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Insurance"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It / Ites"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Manufacturing"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Media And Entertainment"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Metals And Mining"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Oil And Gas"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind22"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pharmaceuticals"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind23"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ports"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind24"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Power"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind25"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Railways"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind26"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Real Estate"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind27"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Renewable Energy"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind28"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Retail"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind29"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Roads"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind30"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Science And Technology"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind31"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Services"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind32"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Steel"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind33"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Telecommunications"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdbtnind35"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tourism And Hospitality"
                android:onClick="selectID"
                />

        </RadioGroup>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try with using SharedPreference object.... save the data in your sharedpreference object on Radio Button Click and get data from sharedpreference where you want.

If you share the code I can help more.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  below is the code and xml.    .java

Comment: Code added above